# Reduced row-echelon form definition of Hoffman's book

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition

[image]

I'm reading Hoffman's linear algebra book and this is my first time studying linear algebra. I'm trying to understand this description of reduced row-echelon form.
I see that $r$ represents rows of matrix but confused about $k_1,\ldots, k_r$ part.

Can some one explain what it means?

Does $k_1$ represents column of first row and if I put $k_1$ for $k_i$, does that mean all columns of that row or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: It means (1) all the rows, except possibly the top, start with $0$s. (2) all rows (including the top) that have non-zero entries will have $1$ as their first (leftmost) non-zero entry. (3) The first non-zero entry for each row will be further to the right than the row above (strictly - no two rows can have their first non-zero entry in the same place). (4) all rows with nothing but $0$s are grouped together at the bottom of the matrix.

Comment: I accidently left out (5) if $k$ is the location of a leading non-zero entry in some row, then the $k^{th}$ entry in every other row is $0$. - not just those below (which is guaranteed by (3)), but also those above.

Comment: I know what it means, just trying to understand how it works with given notations on image.

Comment: Here is an **major** suggestion: If you already know what it means, *don't ask* "Can some one explain what it means?"

Comment: I was asking the meaning of subscripts of k and meaning of r exactly. Didn't asked for general description. If you read you see what i am asking.

Comment: You may have intended to ask about the meaning of the notations exactly, but what you actually asked was first "what it means?". You had given no clue to let us know you knew what Reduced-Row-Echelon-Form was. As far as we knew, the second question was just follow up from your trying to figure out the concept at all. So of course we addressed the broader question, because if you didn't understand that, it was going to be much harder to explain the particular notations.

Comment: I said "this description" and then asked about notations. If i didn't understand the general description then i would use the image with general description or simply ask what is reduced row-echelon form means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $r$ is the number of non-zero rows.
- for each non-zero row $i$, $k_i$ is the column of the first non-zero entry.
- "$R_{ij} = 0$ for $i > r$" means that every row below row $r$, all entries are $0$. (There is an assumed "for all $j$" here, and similar assumptions for other statements.)
- "$R_{ij} = 0$ if $j < k_i$" means that on the non-zero rows, all entries to the left of $k_i$ must be $0$. (Note that the $i$ here is necessarily different than the $i$ in the first part of the statement, as that $i > r$, while $k_i$ is not defined unless $i \le r$.)
- "$R_{ik_j} = \delta_{ij}, 1\le i \le r, 1\le j\le r$" says the column of any $k_j$ will be $0$ except for $R_{jk_j} = 1$ (it only guarantees $0$ for rows up to $r$, but the first condition says rows below $r$ will also have $0$).
- "$k_1 < \dots < k_r$" says that the number of leading $0$s in the first $r$ rows (i.e., before the rows are entirely $0$) strictly increases with each row.

Comment: Thank you that was clear.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, it means,

$1.$ zero rows are at the bottom

$2.$ call first non-zero entry(from left) of a non-zero row, a 'leading entry', then $k_i$ basically represents columns with leading entries and $k_1<k_2<\cdots<k_r$

$3.$ a column with leading entry has all entries zero except leading entry

Comment: My question was how it works with given notations. I already know the definition.

Comment: @Alihanaydın You asked what it means, and that is the answer you have received. You should clarify your question and clarify what exactly it is you are confused about, if you want proper answers

Comment: If you read all, i asked what it means the k_1,…,k_r part not the general description.